# Задание с пересечением 2 неубывающих массивов

Tags: c#, алгоритм, рефакторинг

Насчет дубликатов: {1,2,2,4} пересечение {1,2,2,3} = {1,2,2}.А пересечение {1,2,2,4} и {1,2,3} = {1,2}. Как сделать красивее, лучше, читабельнее?

```
    public static int[] FindIntersection(int[] arrayFirst, int[] arraySecond)
    {
        int[] arrayOfIntersection = new int[CalculateLengthOfIntersectionArray(arrayFirst, arraySecond)];
        int indexOfIntersectedArray = 0;
        int indexOfSecondArrayToStart = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayFirst.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = indexOfSecondArrayToStart; j < arraySecond.Length; j++)
            {
                if (arrayFirst[i] == arraySecond[j])
                {
                    arrayOfIntersection[indexOfIntersectedArray] = arraySecond[j];
                    indexOfIntersectedArray++;
                    indexOfSecondArrayToStart = j + 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return arrayOfIntersection;
    }

    public static int CalculateLengthOfIntersectionArray(int[] arrayFirst, int[] arraySecond)
    {
        int countOfIntersectedElements = 0;
        int indexOfSecondArrayToStart = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayFirst.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = indexOfSecondArrayToStart; j < arraySecond.Length; j++)
            {
                if (arrayFirst[i] == arraySecond[j])
                {
                    indexOfSecondArrayToStart = j + 1;
                    countOfIntersectedElements++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return countOfIntersectedElements;
    }
    

    public static int[] SortArrayAscending(int[] array)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i ++)
            for (int j = i + 1; j < array.Length; j++)
                if (array[i] > array[j])
                {
                    (array[i], array[j]) = (array[j], array[i]);
                }

        return array;
    }
```

Comment: Что значит "можно"? Или они неубывающие, тогда применяете модифицированную процедуру Merge из сортировки слиянием,, либо произвольные, тогда мучаетесь

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ я понял главную свою глупость) Я относительно новичок. Думал находить пересечение неотсортированных массивов, что сложнее. А до merge я пока не дошёл. Пока пилю алгоритмы

Comment: Пересечение неотсортированных проще делать через словари/map. А для начала стоит точно сформулировать, как поставлена задача. Какой должен быть результат? как обходиться с дубликатами?

Comment: `{1,2,2,4} пересечение {1,2,2,3} = {1,2,2}.` А пересечение `{1,2,2,4} и {1,2,3}`?

Comment: OK, код в ответе выполняет `пересечение {1,2,2,4} и {1,2,3} = {1,2}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте попробуем пересечение за линейное время. Пишу прямо здесь, не тестировал.

```
 public static int[] FindIntersection(int[] arrayFirst, int[] arraySecond)
    {
        int len1 = arrayFirst.Length;
        int len2 = arraySecond.Length;
        int[] arrayOfIntersection = new int[min(len1, len2)];
        int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
        while (i < len1 && j < len2) {
            if (arrayFirst[i] < arraySecond[j])
                i++;
            else if (arrayFirst[i] > arraySecond[j])  
                j++;
            else {
               arrayOfIntersection[k++] = arrayFirst[i++];
               j++;
            }
         } 

        //урезать длину arrayOfIntersection до k 

        return arrayOfIntersection;
    }
```

Comment: Всё протестировал, всё круто(только Math.Min вместо min, если брать строго). Насчёт урезать длину, это лучший способ:  arrayOfIntersection = arrayOfIntersection[..k]; ? Я так понимаю такой способ подходит для вычисления разницы множеств. Пойду пробовать. И хотел бы спросить: считается ли дублированием кода то, что находится в теле метода по вычислению длинны и в методе по нахождению массива пересечения? Они отличаются одной строчкой

Comment: @Sheeba334 Да, заодно можно разницу вычислять, только в конце придётся ещё добавить обработку концов массивов. Про лучший способ  уменьшить длину я не знаю, не шарпист. Если урезать длину - то предварительного вычисления её не требуется.

Comment: я понимаю, но чисто фактически это дублирование? И спасибо за ответы и редактирование. Очень информативно

Comment: `чисто фактически это дублирование?` зависит от того, кто как интерпретирует ;) На мой взгляд- да, но вычленение одинакового кода вроде создания итератора по одинаковым элементам непомерно усложняет.

Comment: Кстати, по смыслу (семантически более правильно) для создании результата неизвестного размера больше подходит список, а не массив

Comment: а по поводу разницы:
 нужно в условиях свапнуть строчку с первым if ... { i++} со строчкой arrayOfIntersection[k++] = arrayFirst[i++]; местами и добавить
        while (i < len1)
            {
                arrayOfIntersection[k++] = arrayFirst[i++];
            }
Вполне корректно?

Comment: Вроде да, если имеется  в виду несимметричная разница A \ B